# @TransactionEventListenser not working as expected when transaction inner transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-batch

I try to make event after commit with spring batch and mysql.

And I tried with this example code. (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events)

It works great when using single transaction like this.

```
@Service
public class A {
  @Transactional
  public void logic() {
    // some logics
  }
}


a.logic();

// Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession 

// Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession 
// Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession 
// Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession 

// occuring event

//* ok. it works great. *//
```

But using transaction innner transaction, It's not working as expected....

```
@Service
public class B {

  @Autowired
  private A a;

  @Transactional
  public void logic() {
    // some logics
    a.logic();
    // some logics
  }
}


b.logic();

// Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession (parent transaction start)

// Releasing transactional SqlSession (I think it is child transaction)
// occuring event

// Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession 
// Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession 
// Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession (parent transaction end)

//* I want to occur event after parent transaction but not working as expected *//
```

How can i fix it to occur event after parent transaction???

or Is there anything function for @TransactionalEventListener following first parent transaction???

Comment: Please don't duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966901/transactionaleventlistener-at-spring-batch. `I try to make event after commit with spring batch`: I added an answer in the other question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and Sorry for my duplicate question.

I did becuase didn't know exactly whether `spring batch` or `@TransactionalEventListener` was a problem.