# @TransactionalEventListener at spring batch

Tags: transactions, spring-batch

I want to process something after commit on `spring batch`.

And I tried this example (https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application).

That example works perfectly on `springboot` like this flow.

```
1. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher
2. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher
3. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher
4. commit
5. after commit logic I maked
6. after commit logic I maked
7. after commit logic I maked
```

But on `spring batch` not work as expected.

```
1. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher, and after commit logic
2. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher, and after commit logic
3. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher, and after commit logic
3. commit
```

I doubt `@TransactionalEventListener` or `ApplicationEventPublisher` doesn't work on spring batch.

Is any difference spring context between `springboot` and `spring batch`??

Or for `@TransactionalEventListener`, Is any setting on `spring batch`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. some update query and event publish by ApplicationEventPublisher

Spring Batch does not intercept those events. You need to make your listener participate in one of the step lifecycle events (before/after read, before/after write, etc)

> I want to process something after commit on spring batch.

You can use a [`ChunkListener#afterChunk`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/ChunkListener.html#afterChunk-org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext-) for that, which is called after the transaction is committed.

Comment: @Prajjwal Gupta, done, it was in the pipe. Your comment does not belong to this answer, please remove it.